# Dependencies Output in Subdirectory in .NET 6.0

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, .net-6.0, subdirectory

In .NET Framework, I can put the referenced project in a subdirectory but adding DestinationSubfolder property to the ProjectReference in the .csproj file of the executing assembly. Then I can add the sub directory as probing path in the App.config file and even specify different bindings to specific dlls if I have need of several different versions.

I am trying to do the same with .NET 6.0, but it has proven to be much more difficult.

What I figured out so far is that I can add a runtimeconfig.template.json file to my project and it will that way add a additionalProbingPaths to the .runtimeconfig.json that has been built.
Then if I manually add the *full* path of the created refernce project dll file in the .deps.json file that has been created when I built the project in the following manner, then it will run properly.

```
"ClassLibrary3/1.0.0": {
    "runtime": {
        "D:\\ConsoleAppTest\\ConsoleApp2\\bin\\Debug\\lib\\ClassLibrary3.dll": {}
    }
}
```

However, it does not work when I add a relative path in any configuration I have tried so far.

What I would like to know is the following:

1. How to get it to work with a relative path.
2. How do I add this path before building the solution and not manually after it has been built.
3. If there is a better way of handling this.
4. How to handle different version of the same dll if some projects require it.

Comment: I just edit the csproj file with notepad to use relative path instead of full path.

Comment: @jdweng what is the name of the property that you changed?

Comment: It is the path(s).  I just take the remove the absolute path and replace with a relative path.  Usually it is the sln or csproj or dll.   when debugging I like to keep backup copies of the project(s).  So I take main project and child project and put in a folder.  Then copy the main folder to a new version to do a backup.  Using relative paths nothing has to change after backup is done.  The old and new versions are in completely different folders.

Comment: @jdweng I'm not sure I understand what you mean. In the .csproj file, by default, it is a relative path. When I build the project, the path to the DLL in the deps.json file appears to be relative, as well as it is simply the DLL file as it seems to assume it is in the output folder and not in a subdirectory. When I add a relative path including the subdirectory, it doesn't work. Only if when I replace it with the absolute one in the deps.json.

Comment: The newer version of Visual Studio must of change the default path from Absolute to Relative.  I think you issue with relative path is what folder is being used as the start of the relative path.  The runtime relative path in most cases is the folder where the executable is located (either the debug or release folder in bin).  This is different from the build instructions where the root of the relative is where the csproj file is located.